# Command Line, File Name for each script executed. SQL

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file, command-line, sqlcmd

I have the following files in my folder:

```
Script1.sql
Script2.sql
Script3.sql
```

The below command executes each script successfully:

```
@echo off

set /p sname= Please enter the servername:
set /p dbname= Please enter the databasename:

ECHO started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt

for %%f in (*.sql) do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S %sname% -d %dbname% -i %%f  >>output.txt

%~f0"

    )
pause
```

Results are

```
(1 rows affected)

(3 rows affected)

(2 rows affected)
```

What I would like to know is how can i input the file name after each file is executed and this name stored in the output.txt file ie

```
(1 rows affected)

Script1.sql

(3 rows affected)

Script2.sql

(2 rows affected)

Script3.sql
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just output the file name, what's problem?

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
   echo %%~nf >> output.txt
   sqlcmd.exe  -S %sname% -d %dbname% -i %%f  >>output.txt
)
```

Comment: This only prints the file name in the command line, I need to print it in the output.txt file

Comment: No, Im stuck on this one. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try it now.  It was missing a closing parenthesis.